# How to check for network security config with Androguard in python script

Tags: python, android, xml, androguard

I have an .apk file and want to check wheter the res/xml/network_security_config.xml [1] trusts user supplied certificates.

I read into the androguard docuemntation and I think it should be able to do what I want. However I am confused on how to run code like this from the documentation on an .apk file instead of the already extracted resources.arsc

```
from androguard.core.bytecodes.axml import ARSCParser

with open("resouces.arsc", "rb") as fp:
    res = ARSCParser(fp.read())

# Now you can resolve IDs:
name = res.get_resource_xml_name(0x7F040001)
if name:
    print(name)

# To get the content of an ID, you need to iterate over configurations
# You need to decide which configuration to use...
for config, entry in res.get_res_configs(0x7F040001):
    # You can query `config` for specific configuration
    # or check with `is_default()` if this is a default configuration.
    print("{} = '{}'".format(config.get_qualifier() if not config.is_default() else "<default>", entry.get_key_data()))
```

How would I check whether the res/xml/network_security_config.xml file exists in an .apk file without extracting it and how would I check if it trusts user certificates?
This is all I could figure out so far:

```
from androguard.core.bytecodes import apk
apk_file = apk.APK(app_path)
if 'res/xml/network_security_config.xml' in apk_file.files.keys():
    print("found network_security_config.xml")
```

example network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Edit: found out how to check for the presence of the .xml file and edited my code

[1] https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
apk_file = apk.APK(app_path)
manifest = apk.get_android_manifest_xml()
if 'res/xml/network_security_config.xml' in apk_file.files.keys():
    print("Network Security Config present in .apk")
axml = AXMLPrinter(apk_file.get_file('res/xml/network_security_config.xml'))
axml_obj = axml.get_xml_obj()
for element in axml_obj.iter("certificates"):
    if element.values() == ['user']:
        print("User certificates trusted by network security configuration")
```